# "sudo apt-get update" Malformed entry error

Tags: 16.04, apt, repository, software-sources

I am getting this error while running `sudo apt-get update`:

```
E: Malformed entry 61 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Please provide any suggestions for getting rid of this error.
Here is line 61 from sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ partner
```

Comment: there is an error is a repository listing, can you edit your question and post line 61 of the  file  /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: The line is not complete. It should be like this: `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner` replace "xenial" by whatever your system is.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the distribution you are using is the Ubuntu 16.04 Xenal Xerus codename.
 You need to replace

> deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu partner

with

> deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

Ubuntu Sources List Generator can help you get the source of updates according to your needs.